# JS how to reform this irregular object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this object which its keys are guaranteed sorted and will be used for the operation. And each of its value is a 2d array.

```
var obj = {
  "0": [
    [0, 1], [0, 3], [0, 4]
  ],
  "1": [
    [1, 2], [1, 3]
  ],
  "2": [
    [2, 3], [2, 5]
  ],
  "3": [
    [3, 4], [3, 6]
  ],
  "5": [
    [5, 6]
  ],
  "6": [
    [6, 5]
  ]
}
```

I am trying to concatenate them and for each of its *last value of the array* is the next index of the object. So, my expected result is an array like this,

The pattern is, I have to find a way from `0` which is the first index of `obj`, to the last index which is `6` by using the values in each of it and linking its last array value to the next object. If that makes sense.

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 3, 6]
[0, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 3, 6]
[0, 4]
```

This is my code so far, as I don't know how to proceed further..

```
var result = [];
for (var key in obj) {
    var myarr = obj[key];
    for (var i = 0; i < myarr.length; i++) {
        result.push(myarr[i])
    }
}
```

Any idea or feedback is welcome.

**Edit**

One of the expected result was `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, here's the step by step explanation.

1. The `obj` key starts from `0` and ends in `6`, I have to form a way from `0` to `6` with the arrays in its value.
2. Starts from `obj[0]`, the first array returns `[0, 1]`, save this to `res`. (`res` is now `[0, 1]`)
3. The last value of array in `res` is `1`, now find the next value in `obj[1]`
4. `obj[1]` has two arrays, and ends with `2` or `3`.. So it's possible to append with both of them, so it can be `[0, 1, 2]` or `[0, 1, 3]`. In this case, get the first one which is `[1, 2]` and append the last value to `res`. (`res` is now `[0, 1, 2]`).
5. The last value of array in `res` is now `2`, now find the next value in `obj[2]`.
6. `obj[2]` has two arrays, and ends with `3`, or `5`.. It's possible to append with both of them, so it can be `[0, 1, 2, 3]` or `[0, 1, 2, 5]`. In this case, get the first one which is `[2, 3]` and append the last value to `res`. (`res` is now `[0, 1, 2, 3]`)
7. The last value of array in `res` is now `3`, now find the next value in `obj[3]`.
8. Repeat step 4 or 6. (`res` is now `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`).
9. The last value of array in `res` is now `4`, now find the next value in `obj[4]`.
10. Repeat step 4 or 6. (`res` is now `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`).
11. The last value of array in `res` is now `5`, now find the next value in `obj[5]`.
12. Now value `6` is found which should be the end of iteration if you look at the step `4`. Repeat step 4 or 6. (`res` is now `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`).
13. Repeat from step 1, and form another way to do it, with no duplicates of `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6]`.

Comment: Your input is, in fact and **array of arrays of values**, so you either have some _recursion_ or three levels of loops (and not 2 as in your example).

Comment: I think it's a 2d array because it's just **array of arrays**. Am I mistaken here?

Comment: @DickyBullin : Yes you are mistaken. its a 3d array. currently your code is printing {[0,1],[0,3],[0,4],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[2,5]...........}

Comment: can you explain in detail by how you want the expected output.
I'm unable to understand from given details.

Comment: @SanketTarodekar It iterates the value in the object.. For example, there's value of `[0, 1]`, the last value of it, which is `1`, should be used to find the next value in the `obj[1]` which has the value of `[1, 2], [1, 3]`, and their last value is also used for the next ones until the last value of the object is met which is `6`.

Comment: but in this case 5 returns 6 and 6 5.

Comment: @NinaScholz `obj[5]` has only one array which is `[5, 6]`, the last value of it which is `6`.. Since `6` is the last element in the `obj`, it shouldn't get the value anymore and stops there..

Comment: how does the zero comes into the array for the next loop?

Comment: @NinaScholz `0` is in the `obj[0]`, which the iteration should start. And its containing the value of `[0, 1], [0, 3], [0, 4]`. Iterate those array value, to reach the last one which is `6` by using the array in each of its keys.. I kinda make this sound complicated :(

Comment: ok. lets have a look at the second array `[0, 1, 2, 3, 6]`. how is it build from the first `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`?

Comment: @DickyBullin you are wrong, it is 3D: `obj` is an **array(1)** with the first element of the **array(2)** being `[0, 1], [0, 3], [0, 4]`, meaning another array with three elements, each being an **array(3)** of two elements (e.g. `[0,1]` being the first).

Comment: BTW, I can't figure out how you go from the INPUT to the OUTPUT you presented in the question. Perhaps, you should add some (clear) description of the algorithm.

Comment: @FDavidov I've updated my question.. I hope it's clear now..

Comment: the first loop was always clear, but how do you get the result from array [0...6] to [0...3, 6]? why are the values 4 and 5 skipped?

Comment: @NinaScholz `[0, 3]` is the second array from `obj[0]`. It can only expand to `obj[3]` since 3 is the last value. And in `obj[3]` there's 2 possibilities which is `[3, 4]` and `[3, 6]`.. If it's a `[0, 3, 4]` it will stop there since there is no `obj[4]`, and if it's `[0, 3, 6]` it will also stop because `6` is the last value.

Comment: sorry, i mean how do you go from `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` (line 1) to `[0, 1, 2, 3, 6]` (line 2), without `4` and `5`?

Comment: @DickyBullin `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` is not possible from what I understand. There is no `object[4]`  and so it should stop at `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` Is that right?

Comment: why `[0,1,3,4,5,6]` and `[0,1,3,4]` and not `[0,3,4,5,6]` and `[0,3,4]`?

Comment: Is `[0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,3,6],[0,1,2,5,6],[0,1,3,4],[0,1,3,6],[0,3,4],[0,3,6],[0,4]` the required output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a proposal, with a single extra output, mentioned below.

> ```
> [
>     [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
>     [0, 1, 2, 3, 6],
>     [0, 1, 2, 5, 6],
>     [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6],     /* extended from below                           */
>     [0, 1, 3, 4],           /* original result                               */
>     [0, 1, 3, 6],
>     [0, 3, 4, 5, 6],        /* extended from below                           */
>     [0, 3, 4],              /* extra line, line should not be in result      */
>     [0, 3, 6],              /* but follows the same building rule than above */
>     [0, 4]
> ]
> ```

Basically this solution is building a tree with the given information about linked nodes.

If some nodes are not contiguous, a backtracking  is made for the missing links, with the above function for nodes, `checkNodes` or with `iterPath`, to walk the actual collected nodes for missing items.

```js
function getParts(value, path, nodes) {
    function checkNodes(a) {
        if (a[1] === value + 1) {
            getParts(a[1], path.concat(a[1]), nodes);
            return true;
        }
    }

    function iterPath(k) {
        return (object[k] || []).some(function (a) {
            return path[path.length - 1] + 1 === a[1] || iterPath(a[1]);
        });
    }

    value = value || 0;
    path = path || [value];
    nodes = nodes || [];
    if (object[value]) {
        object[value].forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
            if (a[1] === lastKey) {
                parts.push(path.concat(a[1]));
                return;
            }
            getParts(a[1], path.concat(a[1]), nodes.concat(aa.slice(i + 1)));
        });
        return;
    }
    if (nodes.some(checkNodes)) {
        return;
    }
    path.slice(1).some(iterPath) && getParts(path[path.length - 1] + 1, path.concat(path[path.length - 1] + 1), nodes);
    parts.push(path);
}

var object = {
        0: [[0, 1], [0, 3], [0, 4]],
        1: [[1, 2], [1, 3]],
        2: [[2, 3], [2, 5]],
        3: [[3, 4], [3, 6]],
        5: [[5, 6]],
        6: [[6, 5]]
    },
    lastKey = 6,
    parts = [];

getParts();
parts.forEach(function (a) { console.log(JSON.stringify(a)); });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Brilliant! Even today I just found out the algorithm I'm looking for is either A* or Dijkstra algorithm which is used more likely for pathfinding, which is almost exactly what my problem is. But, this is the code I'm looking for. Thank you so much..

Answer (score 3):

Well, I was sitting on this for some time now, and sharing across my take on the problem:

The input object can be considered as an ***adjacency list*** of a tree:

```
var obj={0:[[0,1],[0,3],[0,4]],1:[[1,2],[1,3]],2:[[2,3],[2,5]],3:[[3,4],[3,6]],5:[[5,6]],6:[[6,5]]};
```

and the following as the result required, which is in fact, as I see it, the list of all ***root-to-leaf paths*** of the tree:

```
[0,1,2,3,4]
[0,1,2,3,6]
[0,1,2,5,6]
[0,1,3,4]
[0,1,3,6]
[0,3,4]
[0,3,6]
[0,4]
```

a little different than the result set mentioned in the question which is the below:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
[0,1,2,3,6]
[0,1,2,5,6]
[0,1,3,4,5,6]
[0,1,3,4]
[0,1,3,6]
[0,3,4,5,6]
[0,3,6]
[0,4]
```

The ***difference*** between the results is only the question *whether 4 and 6 are leaf nodes*

**Solution**:

So I assume that for our Tree here:

1. **0** is the root node
2. **4** and **6** are the leaf nodes

See code below - I created a tree first, and from that listed out all the *root to leaf paths*:

```js
// removed "6:[[6,5]]" as 6 is a 'leaf' of the tree
var obj={0:[[0,1],[0,3],[0,4]],1:[[1,2],[1,3]],2:[[2,3],[2,5]],3:[[3,4],[3,6]],5:[[5,6]]};

var availableNodes = Object.keys(obj);

var tree = availableNodes.reduce(function(hash) {
  return function(prev, curr) {
    hash[curr] = hash[curr] || {};
    hash[curr].children = hash[curr].children || [];
    obj[curr].forEach(function(element) {
      hash[element[1]] = hash[element[1]] || {};
      hash[element[1]].children = hash[element[1]].children || [];
      hash[curr].rootPath = hash[curr].rootPath || [];
      hash[curr].children.push({value: element[1],children: hash[element[1]].children});
    });
    curr && prev.push({value: curr,children: hash[curr].children});
    return prev;
  };
}(Object.create(null)), []);

//console.log(JSON.stringify(tree));

var result = [];

function rootToLeafPaths(node, path) {
  path.push(+node.value);
  if (node.children.length === 0) {
    result.push(Array.from(path));
    path.pop();
  } else {
    node.children.forEach(function(element) {
      rootToLeafPaths(element, path);
    });
    path.pop();
  }
}

rootToLeafPaths(tree[0], []);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```